# What are all the standard methods available to solve a general ODE into infinite series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

What are all the standard methods available to solve a general ODE into infinite series?

For example, the Taylor method.

I am very curious.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Julien - Is it better right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether there are standard methods for solving general ODEs, then the answer is no.  Solutions to non-linear ODE's are often pursued on a case-by-case basis.  In special cases, a closed-form solution is possible, while in most cases, closed-form or quasi-closed-form solutions are not possible, and the analyst pursued only numerical approximations to solutions.  And in other cases, solutions are simply non-existent.

Comment: Can you find any reference for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are numerical approximation always possible if an solution exists?

Comment: Interestingly, it is not always trivial to show that a "reasonable" numerical approximation of solution to (even) a linear ODE converges (as the approximation is refined in a limiting sense) to the solution of that linear ODE.

Comment: If a solution exists, can an approximate solution always be found using Taylor series around some point at least?

Comment: No, not in general.